# Qual a melhor Forma de fazer estes Triggers?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Gostaria de saber se existe uma melhor forma para escrever estes trigger. agradeço

```html
--gatilho para gravar os dados do usuário 
CREATE TRIGGER TGR_TB_USUARIO_INSERT
 ON TB_USUARIO
 FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @IDUSUARIO INT
   SELECT @IDUSUARIO = IDUSUARIO FROM TB_USUARIO
   UPDATE TB_USUARIO SET  EXCLUIR_CADASTRO = 'N', DATA_CADASTRO = CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 20) WHERE IDUSUARIO = @IDUSUARIO
END
GO

--gatilho para exclusão dos dados do usuário 
CREATE TRIGGER TGR_TB_USUARIO_UPDATE
 ON TB_USUARIO
 FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @EXCLUIR CHAR(1)
   DECLARE @IDUSUARIO INT
   SELECT @EXCLUIR = EXCLUIR_CADASTRO, @IDUSUARIO = IDUSUARIO FROM TB_USUARIO 

   IF (@EXCLUIR = 'S')
     BEGIN
      UPDATE TB_USUARIO SET  EXCLUIR_CADASTRO = 'S', DATA_EXCLUSAO = CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 20), DATA_CADASTRO = NULL WHERE IDUSUARIO = @IDUSUARIO
     END

     IF (@EXCLUIR = 'N')
     BEGIN
      UPDATE TB_USUARIO SET  EXCLUIR_CADASTRO = 'N', DATA_CADASTRO = CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 20), DATA_EXCLUSAO = NULL WHERE IDUSUARIO = @IDUSUARIO
     END   

END
GO
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes de mais, alguns comentários sobre a tua implementação. Em minha opnião nenhum dos casos justifica a utilização de um trigger.

- O primeiro trigger tem como objectivo, quando um novo utilizador é inserido na tabela `TB_USUARIO`, actualizar a coluna `EXCLUIR_CADASTRO` com o valor 'N' e a coluna `DATA_CADASTRO` com a data do sistema. Isto pode ser feito na mesma instrução de `INSERT`, não sendo necessária a criação de um trigger. Bastaria fazer:

```
INSERT INTO TB_USUARIO(id, username, excluir_cadastro, data_cadastro)
VALUES(123, 'NomeUtilizador', 'N', GETDATE()) -- Por defeito, quando o utilizador é inserido a flag fica com valor 'N' e a DATA_CADASTRO é a data do sistema
```

- O segundo trigger tem como objectivo, quando um utilizador é removido, actualizar as colunas `EXCLUIR_CADASTRO, DATA_EXCLUSAO e DATA_CADASTRO`. Uma vez mais, este comportamento poderia ser obtido aquando da execução da instrução de `UPDATE` e sem recorrer a um trigger. Ficaria, de forma equivalente:

```
UPDATE TB_USUARIO
   SET  EXCLUIR_CADASTRO = @excluirCadastro, 
       ,DATA_CADASTRO = CASE WHEN @excluirCadastro = 'N' THEN GETDATE() ELSE NULL END -- Porque actualizar a data de cadastro quando actualizas o utilizador? Não seria mais correcto ter uma coluna DATA_DE_ALTERACAO?
       ,DATA_EXCLUSAO = CASE WHEN @excluirCadastro = 'S' THEN GETDATE() ELSE NULL END 
  WHERE IDUSUARIO = @idUsuario
```

Para finalizar, e apenas por uma questão de completar a resposta e responder à tua questão inicial, podes criar um trigger um pouco mais genérico para tratar os dois casos. Para aceder aos valores que foram inseridos ou actualizados deves usar as tabelas lógicas inserted ou deleted.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TGR_TB_USUARIO ON TB_USUARIO AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS

   DECLARE @action CHAR(1) = ' '

   IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted)
      SET @action = CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted) THEN 'U' ELSE 'I' END; -- Se existir um registo nas duas tabelas então trata-se de um update, caso apenas exista na tabela inserted então é um insert
   ELSE RETURN; 

   UPDATE TB_U 
      SET  TB_U.EXCLUIR_CADASTRO = CASE 
                                      WHEN @action = 'I' THEN 'N' -- Inserir novo utilizador, acção: Actualizar excluir_cadastro com valor 'N'
                                      WHEN @action = 'U' THEN tb.excluir_cadastro  -- actualizar utlizador, acção: NADA
                                   END 
          ,TB_U.DATA_CADASTRO = CASE 
                                     WHEN @action = 'U' AND inserted.EXCLUIR_CADASTRO = 'S' THEN NULL --Actualizar utilizador (excluir) acção: actualizar data_cadastro para NULL
                                     ELSE GETDATE() --Inserir novo utilizador ou actualizar, acção: Actualizar data_cadastro com data do sistema
                                END
          ,TB_U.DATA_EXCLUSAO = CASE WHEN inserted.EXCLUIR_CADASTRO = 'S' THEN GETDATE() ELSE NULL END  
     FROM TB_USUARIO TB_U
     INNER JOIN inserted
       ON inserted.IDUSUARIO = TB_U.IDUSUARIO  -- Assumindo que IDUSUARIO é chave primária na tabela TB_USUARIO
END
GO
```

Comment: excelente resposta, muito grato por compartilhar o seu conhecimento.